# Can I listen primary machine's UDP Protocol in second machine without primary's machine receiving UDP protokol?

Tags: udp, qudpsocket

I have two PCs. One of them primary PC and have a UDP socket from sensor and getting packets. I want to save the packets in another (secondary) PC. But i don't want to broadcast to packets to all PCs those only primary PC will get packets, secondary PC will listen to primary PC. Is it possible?

[Picture Describes to PCs and Sensor connection between Primary PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KKMF.png)

In the above picture there is a sensor and connect to primary PC. Sensor sending a value to primary PC and secondary PC listens to primary PC. After listening to primary PC without getting value from secondary PC to sensor we will save the values to file. This thought is possible in UDP Protocol?

If it is possible i will code in QT Creater in C++.

Thank you.

I read QAbstractClass and QUdpSocket Class in QT Classes. I think it's possible but i have a questions. Can we listen before do we bind to port?